# what is alternative/opposite to piecemeal statistical approach?

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, univariate

I have only basic knowledge about bio-statistics. For not normally distributed data, I used Kruskal-Wallis test to investigate the statistical significance between different variables. I performed an exercise with three different intensities (different weights w1, w2, w3), then with one weight at three different speeds (s1, s2, s3). The readings were observed from 3 different points(p1, p2, p3).

I opted for statistical significance among p1, p2, p3 at (w1 and w2 and w3) and at (s1 and s2 and s3). then i opted statistical significance among w1, w2, w3 for p1 and p2 and p3. then i opted statistical significance among s1, s2, s3 for p1 and p2 and p3. So, there are 36 independent Kruskal-Wallis tests.

After that, Mann-Whitney test was performed for pairs (post hoc analysis).

I got comment on the test that, "the piecemeal statistical approach, consisting of a very large number of comparisons made between dependent variables during different conditions, **without corrections for multiple testing**, renders it probable that “significant” results may well be due to chance."

Can someone please suggest where I am wrong, and how and where to adjust the *p* value?

Answer (score 0):

So far, what i found about this particular problem, it should be done by repeated measures of ANOVA, with Bonferroni method for posthoc.
The reason is the data is not independent. The *p* value is needed to be adjusted for multiple tests.